# NSURLConnection vs. NSData + GCD

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

`NSData` has always had a very convenient method called `+dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`. While convenient, it also blocks execution of the current thread, which meant it was basically useless for production code (Ignoring `NSOperation`). I used this method so infrequently, I completely forgot that it existed. Until recently.

The way I've been grabbing data from the tubes is the standard `NSURLConnectionDelegate` approach: Write a download class that handles the various `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods, gradually build up some data, handle errors, etc. I'll usually make this generic enough to be reused for as many requests as possible.

Say my typical downloader class runs somewhere in the ballpark of 100 lines. That's 100 lines to do asynchronously what `NSData` can do synchronously in one line. For more complexity, that downloader class needs a delegate protocol of its own to communicate completion and errors to its owner, and the owner needs to implement that protocol in some fashion.

Now, enter Grand Central Dispatch, and I can do something as fantastically simple as:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {

    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
    // Process data, also async...

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        // Back to the main thread for UI updates, etc.
    });
});
```

And I can throw that sucker in anywhere I want, right in-line. No need for a download class, no need to handle connection delegate methods: Easy async data in just a few lines. The disparity between this approach and my pre-GCD approach is of a magnitude great enough to trigger the Too Good to be True Alarm.

Thus, my question: Are there any caveats to using `NSData` + GCD for simple data download tasks instead of `NSURLConnection` (Assuming I don't care about things like download progress)?

Comment: cant cancel the request for one..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are losing a lot of functionality here:

- Can't follow the download progression
- Can't cancel the download
- Can't manage the possible authentication process
- You can't handle errors easily, which is **really important** especially in mobile development like on iPhone of course (because you often lose your network in real conditions, so it is very important to track such network error cases when developing for iOS)

and there's probably more I guess.

---

The right approach for that is to create a class than manages the download.

See my own [`OHURLLoader`](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHURLLoader) class for example, which is simple and I made the API to be easy to use with blocks:

```
NSURL* url = ...
NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

OHURLLoader* loader = [OHURLLoader URLLoaderWithRequest:req];
[loader startRequestWithCompletion:^(NSData* receivedData, NSInteger httpStatusCode) {
    NSLog(@"Download of %@ done (statusCode:%d)",url,httpStatusCode);
    if (httpStatusCode == 200) {
        NSLog(%@"Received string: %@", loader.receivedString); // receivedString is a commodity getter that interpret receivedData using the TextEncoding specified in the HTTP response
    } else {
        NSLog(@"HTTP Status code: %d",httpStatusCode); // Log unexpected status code
    }
} errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error while downloading %@: %@",url,error);
}];
```

*See the [README file](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHURLLoader) and sample project on github for more info.*

This way:

- you still rely on the asynchronous methods provided by NSURLConnection (and **[as the Apple's documentation says about Concurrency Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide)** if an API already exists to make asynchronous tasks, use it instead of relying on another threading technology if possible)
- you keep advantages of NSURLConnection (error handlings, etc)
- but you also have the advantages of the blocks syntax that makes your code more readable than when using delegate methods

Comment: I agree with you on progress indication, cancellation, and authentication. All good points. Error handling, on the other hand, I would have expected be possible via the error: argument to the method. If that's not the case, it would certainly be a major downside.

Comment: You may have some error handling if you use `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` but not if you use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` only as in your code in your question. But moreover, you then will only have network errors, not HTTP errors, nor access to headers, etc.

Comment: +1 Great answer. Loved your OHURLLoader, it was a real treat to use!

Comment: Thanks! Note that since I wrote this answer, Apple has added a new method (available since iOS5) to `NSURLConnection`, to perform asynchronous requests using blocks (so my old `OHURLLoader` is not really needed anymore). See `+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` in the documentation for more details.

Comment: @user298261 I don't understand your comment: `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]` does contain the `NSURLResponse` parameter in its completion block, which has every needed information, including the `MIMEType` property. And even before this method was available (prior to iOS5), the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` already had that `NSURLResponse` information in a dedicated delegate method.

Comment: Ah. Well, then I spoke too soon. I didn't realize that was the case. Thank you for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 12):

**[WWDC 2010 Session Videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/):**

- WWDC 2010 Session 207 - Network Apps for iPhone OS, Part 1
- WWDC 2010 Session 208 - Network Apps for iPhone OS, Part 2

The lecturer said

> "Threads Are Evil™".

For network programming, it is strongly recommended to use asynchronous API with RunLoop.

Because, if you use NSData + GCD like the following, it uses one thread per connection.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
```

And it's likely to use many connections and many threads. It is too easy to use GCD :-)
Then, many threads eats huge amount of memory for its stack.
Thus, you'd better to use asynchronous API as AliSoftware said.

Answer (score 2):

As of OS X v10.9 and iOS 7 the preferred way is to use [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html). It gives you a nice, block-based interface and features like canceling, suspending and background downloading.